# Recaptcha in salesforce community

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-community, iframe

I have tried out the recaptcha in lightning component using VF page as iframe and it is working absolutely fine,but when i tried that component in salesforce community it's not working[image: Throws this error].
I added the community domain in recaptcha settings but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the key and generating the new one? Like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30739220/4182384)

Comment: Sorry ,i forgot to update the solution,i added the the URL which will there when someone log in to the community and was testing by previewing it which changed the URL.

Comment: Ok you can answer it your own and can close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added the the URL which will there when someone log in to the community and was testing by previewing it which changed the URL,that's why it was not working.